# bashrc w/awk print alias problem escaping quotes

Tags: bash

Below, the command works great as I'd like. However, inside **.bashrc** it does not run due to termination of strings. Any advice is happy :)

```
ps aux | awk '{print $4 "%\t" int($6/1024) " MB\t" $11}' | sort -n
```

I am simply trying to add something like: `alias memusage='command'` or `function memusage { command }`

Comment: What seems to be the problem?

Comment: Write a function in your `.bashrc`, e.g. `mypsaux () { ps aux | awk '{print $4 "%\t" int($6/1024) " MB\t" $11}' | sort -n; }` and then alias it later, e.g. `memusage=mypsaux`. (add the trialing `';'` after `sort -n;` if you write it all on one line)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Is there any reason to use an alias to a function, rather than just using the function directly?

Comment: Nope, it just looked like in the question the OP wanted an aliast to `memusage` so I added it. (could just call the function `memusage`)

Comment: @JREAM The `alias memusage='command'` syntax won't work here, because the command itself contains single-quotes, and quotes don't nest. Functions don't have this problem, so just use a function.

Answer (score 0):

For `alias`, replace the inner `'`s with `'"'"'`s:

```
$ alias memusage='ps aux | awk '"'"'{print $4 "%\t" int($6/1024) " MB\t" $11}'"'"' | sort -n'
```

Testing it:

```
$ memusage | grep MEM
%MEM%   0 MB    COMMAND
```

Answer (score 0):

To keep both memusage alias and original commands, you can put this in .bashrc :

```
alias memusage="$(cat << 'EOF'
ps aux | awk '{print $4 "%\t" int($6/1024) " MB\t" $11}' | sort -n
EOF
)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to define it as a function:

```
memusage() {
    ps aux | awk '{print $4 "%\t" int($6/1024) " MB\t" $11}' | sort -n
}
```

If you define it on one line, you need a semicolon before the close brace:

```
memusage() { ps aux | awk '{print $4 "%\t" int($6/1024) " MB\t" $11}' | sort -n; }
```

Note that the `function` keyword is a nonstandard bashism; the standard function definition just has `()` after the name.